# Joomla website optimzation using JCH Optimzation

Tags: javascript, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I have installed JCH optimize plugin in my Joomla Website. When I select the "Intermediate" option this plugin is working fine but the website is very slow.

When I select the "Average", My website speed is increase around 25%. but there is the some JS error during merging. We can see many of errors in firebug.

Can anyone know that how can I optimize website speed and also want to increase the website grade in google? Right now it is 45.
Can we use another plugin or any library for this or any other option in JCH optimize plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had good success with JCH Optimize and by using it and some other techniques I've been able to get our Google PageSpeed score into [the high 90s](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.panchroma.ca%2Fen%2F&tab=desktop)

Here's what helped me with JCH Optimize.

- Clear your site and browser cache
- Do everything suggested by [the utility settings](https://www.jch-optimize.net/documentation/utility-settings.html)
- Start at the lowest automatic setting and check for any errors
- When you're sure there aren't any errors, increase JCH Optimize one level, save, and repeat. Again, be careful to clear your cache
- Important not to proceed to next level until you've fixed all errors ;)
- According to [this table](https://www.jch-optimize.net/documentation/automatic-settings-group.html#automatic-settings-table) on the JCH website, if you aren't changing  the defaults the only difference between the Intermediate and Average settings is that Average is including third party extensions. Use the options under the [exclude tab](https://www.jch-optimize.net/documentation/resolving-conflicts-by-excluding-offending-files.html) to try and fix any conflicts
- I'm using JCH Optimize in combination with [mod_pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/) which was a complicating factor. I can get them to play well together if I first disable JCH, load pages on our site so that mod_pagespeed has time to optimise images and scripts, and then activate JCH
- There are a lot of options with this extension, and every site is different. [JCH is well documented](https://www.jch-optimize.net/documentation.html) and it's worth reading the manual more than once and taking the time to figure out what will and will not work on your site.

Good luck!

Comment: I have try to do some of points which you have given me. there are some default errors are showing in my website so i need to fix that error first?

Comment: > there are some default errors are showing in my website so i need to fix that error first? ...  for sites I've worked on, I found it was best to fix  errors at each step before increasing the JCH level. Otherwise I had too many small fires to try and fix and it was difficult to locate their cause.